# How to open a file with the system's webbrowser?

Tags: genie

I have made a function that creates a html file. How to open it in the browser in the user's system?

In python I would import webbrower and then call webbrowser.open("file.html").

How to achieve the same result in genie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python `webbrowser` module is a cross platform way of opening a browser window. I'm not aware of a similar cross platform module for Genie or Vala, so you will have to use platform specific commands.

On a Linux based platform `xdg-open` is the command to open an application in a standard way across desktops. This should work on modern versions of Gnome, KDE, XFCE and others.

Since GLib 2.40 the preferred way to open an external command in Genie is to use GLib GIO's GSubprocess. In Genie this would be something like:

```
init
    try
        var command = new Subprocess( SubprocessFlags.NONE,
                                      "xdg-open",
                                      "http://stackoverflow.com/tags/genie/"
                                      )
        command.wait()
    except error:Error
        print error.message
```

This needs to be compiled with the GIO package:

```
valac --pkg gio-2.0 my_xdg_open_example.gs
```

The example above waits for the command to complete, GSubprocess can be used asynchronously. You can also access STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR easily. See [Subprocess - Valadoc](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.Subprocess.Subprocess) and [SubprocessFlags - Valadoc](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.SubprocessFlags)

This can also be used to open local files in a web browser as long as the MIME-type for that file has been configured to open in a browser. HTML files should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

One posible option for linux is:

Process.spawn_command_line_async ("sensible-browser file.html")

Comment: Other option is create your own browser: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/WebKitSample